# How to retain contents of datagrid view when applying multiple filters

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, filtering

I am trying to provide my users a nice search capability.   I want to do so using textboxes to filter a datagridview.   I have a dgv containing all animals in the database.  For simplicity sake let’s say the first two columns are animalName and animal (dog or cat).  I have two textboxes used for filtering, one for each of those two columns.  Let's say I want to find all dogs named Buddy.  In my first text box I type 'Buddy' and, because of the filter code behind the textbox change event the dgv now contains only the Buddys.  When I go to textboxAnimal and type 'd' for dog the dgv changes to show all the dogs; not just the ones named Buddy.  How can I make it such that the results of the first filter stay in place when I apply the second filter?

I assume I need to use the lostFocus (or gotFocus or leave) event of the first textbox but just don’t know what code to put behind it.   I guess I could hard code a select statement that would then be used to repopulate the datagridview but this could get onerous as I’m going to have many textboxes; not just two.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I forgot to say that I'm writing in visual basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focus is irrelevant. You handle the `TextChanged` event of both `TextBox` controls and you build the filter from scratch every time, taking both fields into account, e.g.

```
Private Sub TextBoxes_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged,
                                                                            TextBox2.TextChanged
    Me.BindingSource1.Filter = String.Format("Column1 LIKE '%{0}%' AND Column2 LIKE '%{1}%'",
                                             TextBox1.Text,
                                             TextBox2.Text)
End Sub
```

One pitfall of filtering on `TextChanged`, regardless of how many fields you're filtering on, is that you will end up filtering needlessly several times when the user types several letters.  For instance, if the user intends to type "bud" then there's no point to filtering after the "b" and the "bu" and it may actually degrade performance if the data set is large.  For that reason, it's nice to use a `Timer` to delay filtering for a short period.  That will defer filtering until the user stops typing in most cases.  You can play with the `Interval` to get the performance you want.  Probably about 500 ms should do it but it's up to you.

```
Private Sub TextBoxes_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged,
                                                                            TextBox2.TextChanged
    'Start or restart the timer because the user typed something.
    Me.Timer1.Stop()
    Me.Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    'The timer has expired so the user has not typed anything for the prescribed amount of time.
    Me.BindingSource1.Filter = String.Format("Column1 LIKE '%{0}%' AND Column2 LIKE '%{1}%'",
                                             TextBox1.Text,
                                             TextBox2.Text)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you jmc.  I understand your approach and like the idea of the timer.  I'm having some trouble with the implementation though.  Currently, in the form load event I fill the dgv with all the animals by a select statement and then a fillgrid subroutine that has:
 With dgvAnimals
 .DataSource = dsAnimals.Tables("dtAnimals")
End With.

To implement your solution I think that after each textbox change (and timer elapse) I need to execute a new select statement (just like the one you gave me) and repeat the fillgrid subroutine.  Does that make sense?

Comment: jmc, it works like a champ.  Thank you.  I'm no longer dead in the water.  I'm marking this thread as solved.

Comment: Just in case you hadn't realised, my intention was that you would populate a `DataTable`, bind that to a `BindingSource` and then bind that to the grid.  The code I provided then sets the `Filter` property of the `BindingSource` and that filters the visible data.

Comment: I'm not real literate when it comes to binding and binding sources. Although I've heard the phrase many times I've never been quite sure what it means.  But, no matter, I took your code and put it into my form and with a couple of small mods; it worked just fine.  This facility is going to be super for my users. Thanks.

Comment: BindingSource is a class, just like Form, Button or DataTable.  It's a component, so you can add it to a form in the designer, or you can create it in code.  It provides a one-stop-shop for data bound between a source and one or more controls, i.e. navigation, editing, etc.

Comment: I'll study this as I want to understand it better.  I've seen 'binding' and 'bound' and 'unbound' way too many times to not have a good understanding of it.  I think I've been creating this binding in code but not having a very deep understanding of what I've been doing.  I've never worked with a timer before either but am adding it now to the form and it will work good.   In fact the whole thing is going to work really well and I'm excited to show my users.  They'll think I'm brilliant when all I did was ask you!